no such file: pdfmake font issue in prod with vercel (astro)
I've implemented a pdf download from an api route /api/export in Astro, it works good in localhost, but in prod it fails. I've tried literally everything... even after that, I've not been able to make it work.
This issue is very common, and everyone who is asking for this problem, seems like they weren't able to fix it because are no comment in the threads...
The issue is the custom fonts used in pdf are not found in the vercel deploy:

I've this for fonts settings:
import path from "path";
import type { TFontFamilyTypes } from "pdfmake/interfaces";

const pathToFonts: string = path.join(
  process.cwd(),
  "public",
  "resources",
  "fonts",
);

const fonts: Record<string, TFontFamilyTypes> = {
  Roboto: {
    normal: path.join(pathToFonts, "Roboto-Regular.ttf"),
    bold: path.join(pathToFonts, "Roboto-Bold.ttf"),
    italics: path.join(pathToFonts, "Roboto-Italic.ttf"),
    bolditalics: path.join(pathToFonts, "Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf"),
  },
};

export { fonts };

All my fonts are located in the public folder /public/resources/fonts/...

I also tried this in my astro config file:
adapter: vercel({
  functionPerRoute: true,
  includeFiles: [
    "./public/resources/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf",
    "./public/resources/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf",
    "./public/resources/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf",
    "./public/resources/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf",
  ],
}),

https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/vercel/#includefiles
The build output:

But it doesn't work.
I also tried /resources/fonts/... instead /public/resources/fonts/..., the issue must be something else.
I'm requiring your help 

Probably I am wrong, but is it possible that file names may be cause? Just for experimental purposes, try to rename files to have only letters in their names, for example rename Roboto-Regular.ttf to RobotoRegular.ttf, and all other files too. And change their references.

I just did it, the issue persists.
